# Setting focus and blur events on Iframe body not working with firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, onblur, onfocus

I have created an editable iFrame as :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="editor"></iframe>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.designMode="on";                                       
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.close();

    $("#editor").contents().find("body").blur(function(){ // Blur functions });

    $("#editor").contents().find("body").focus(function(){// focus functions });

</script>
```

Focus and Blur events are getting triggered in chrome but not working for firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved as :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="editor"></iframe>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.designMode="on";                                       
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.close();

if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1){
    $("#editor").contents().bind('blur', function(){ // Blur functions });
    $("#editor").contents().bind('focus', function(){ // focus functions });
}else{
    $("#editor").contents().find("body").blur(function(){ // Blur functions });
    $("#editor").contents().find("body").focus(function(){ // focus functions });
}
</script>
```

For firefox it works with focus/blur set on contents() not for body.

Comment: The code for firefox doesn't work for me unfortunately, only if I put in an alert before the blur/focus functions like this:

`if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1){
    alert("Firefox");
    $("#editor").contents().bind('blur', function(){ // Blur functions });
    $("#editor").contents().bind('focus', function(){ // focus functions });
}`